# Wt connect function, passing a parameter to a function which is a connect function argument

Tags: c++, arguments, bind, wt

The following code snippet uses Wt/C++ connect which takes two arguments.
How to pass an argument to &mode::func.

```
button = new WPushButton("func 1", buttons);
stuff()->addWidget(button);
button->clicked().connect(this, &mode::func);
```

In other words, how to make &mode::func(number). Look the desired code below.

```
int number = 5;
button = new WPushButton("func 1", buttons);
stuff()->addWidget(button);
button->clicked().connect(this, &mode::func(number));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Wt 4 will be released soon, I'll mention how it can be done in Wt 4 too.

## For Wt 3:

If you connect a function like that, then `mode::func` will be called with the `WMouseEvent` of the clicked signal if it takes an argument. You could use `boost::bind` instead:

```
int number = 5;
button = new WPushButton("func 1");
stuff()->addWidget(button);
button->clicked().connect(boost::bind(&mode::func, this, number));
```

This will still automatically disconnect the slot if `this` is deleted, just like your original code. If you use `std::bind` (or a lambda) instead, it won't automatically disconnect the slot.

I removed the `buttons` argument from your original code, because it sets `buttons` as the parent, but subsequently moves it to `stuff()` using `addWidget`, making that the parent.

## For Wt 4:

In Wt 4, you will have to use `std::bind` or a lambda function. You could do it like this:

```
int number = 5;
button = stuff()->addWidget(std::make_unique<WPushButton>("func 1"));
button->clicked().connect(bindSafe([this,number]{
  func(number);
}));
```

`bindSafe` makes sure that the lambda is not called after `this` is deleted.

You can omit `bindSafe` if you don't want to guard against deletion of `this`. In many practical cases `button` is deleted before `this`, making `bindSafe` unnecessary.